# Get factor levels as comma separated single character

Tags: r, csv

I have a case where a data frame column is factor.
`levels(df$col1)` will get me levels encloused in double quotes.

```
> levels(risk_register_data$Division)
[1] "Commercial"    "Group Finance"

> as.character(levels(risk_register_data$Division))
[1] "Commercial"    "Group Finance"

> csv_char <- as.character(levels(risk_register_data$Division))
> csv_char
[1] "Commercial"    "Group Finance"
> paste("Levels are: ", csv_char)
[1] "Levels are: Commercial"    "Levels are: Group Finance"
```

I want output in this way, so that I can use it as ggplot's title, annotation or text:

```
> csv_char
> [1] "Levels are: Commercial, Group Finance"
```

Any suggestion, how it can be done ?

Comment: `paste(levels(...), collapse=", ")`? (For instance, `paste(levels(iris$Species), collapse = ", ")` produces a single string, `"setosa, versicolor, virginica"`.)

Comment: Please write it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Or use `toString`: `paste("Levels are:", toString(levels(risk_register_data$Division)))`

Answer (score 1):

As *@Maurits-Evers* also suggests we could use `toString`.

***Example***

```
lev <- paste0("Levels are: ", toString(levels(iris$Species)))
plot(iris[c(1, 4)], col=iris$Species, main="Iris", sub=lev, cex.sub=.8)
```

[image]